# Java/MYSQL - data processing within resultset

Tags: java, mysql

My Java program retrieves a large amount of data from my database (localhost / MYSQL). I do 100-200 queries where the result set returned from each query contains 3000-10000 rows. Each rows has 8 columns that contains timeStamp, double, Bigdecimal etc.

After each query I run through each row and depending on row data do some calculations. I am the only one using the database so too many connections and queries is not a factor.

At this point I do the data processing within the result set / while-loop. It works fine, however I need to extend the number of calculations. Among other things I need to do some comparing of data between rows.

Before I rewrite the entire code one question: would it be smarter to create a class and then for each row within the result set, create an object -> put it into an Array

- close connection to DB
- do the calculation
- save result (in a file or DB)
- do query number 2
- create an object for each row
- add to array
- close connection and so on....

My project will not end up as final product. The purpose of the project is to test a number of hypothesis.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: It's hard to say anything definite since you're being too broad, but one rule stands always: do as much work as possible in the database before returning results to the application.

Comment: Hi Kayaman - my apologies for this late response.

Comment: The calculation needed are not that complicated. But there are calculations to be made. And i need a result for each row. I am aware of the fact, that I should delegate as much calculation to the DB as possible. At present I am running code as described above. Works fine - savings by letting DB do calculation is in milliseconds. The program will not have multiply user. Only one. Processing power not a factor.